# Get rows from Cassandra table, which matches column1 = '123' or column2 = '123'

Tags: cassandra

I came to know that Cassandra doesn't support OR in where clause, but I need an equivalent for the following query :

```
select * from table where column1 = '123' or column2 = '123';
```

As OR is not supported in Cassandra can I use Batch queries like the following and combine the result in the program and is it efficient?

```
[ select * from table where column1 = '123' , select * from table where column2 = '123']
```

If not is there any way to achieve the above stated simple logic.

In my case, both column1 and column2 together are the Primary key. i.e. composite partition key.

Can I combine column1 and column2 as a list [column1, column2] and query like :

```
select * from table where list contains '123';
```

and creating secondary index on the list

Comment: Also `BATCH` in Cassandra does't do what you think it does.  It applies operations _atomically_.  There is nothing to be gained by applying `SELECT`s atomically.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can't query with or, also you can't execute these two queries without using secondary index or [allow filtering](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2014/12/allow-filtering-explained).

```
select * from table where column1 = '123' 
select * from table where column2 = '123'
```

according to these queries, possibilities are;

- `column1` or `column2` is partition key
- `column1` and `column2` are partition key
- one of them is partition key and other is clustering key.

and you can't query them according to these possibilities. If you want to query them without `allow filtering`, then you need to create secondary index. After that you can make two queries and compare them on your application layer. Secondary index is not a silver bullet, there are drawbacks which are well explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944845/why-secondary-indexes-are-less-efficient-in-cassandra) and [here](https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes).

If you need those type of `or` queries then it may be better to redesign your tables according to the queries to avoid secondary indexes like these or allow filtering.